# Use MSSQL stored procedure with parameters in Laravel 4

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, laravel, laravel-4

For a project we are using a MSSQL database. I want to use Laravel 4 to access a stored procedure in the database. I manage to do this in the following way:

```
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
$stmt = $pdo ->prepare('getArticles');
$stmt->execute();
```

But if the stored procedure expects parameters, I don't know how to pass them through. For a regular select, this works:

```
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $pdo ->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(213));
```

But when I try the following for the stored procedure, it gives me an error:

```
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
$stmt = $pdo ->prepare('getTurnover(?,?)');
$stmt->execute(array(1, 2013));
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to send parameter to the stored procedure? If so, how?

EDIT:
The error I get is:

> PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: message: Incorrect syntax near '1'. (severity 15)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
$stmt = $pdo ->prepare('CALL getTurnover(?,?)');
$stmt->execute(array(1, 2013));
```

in anycase, read this http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Hi Maxim, I did try this as well. To add the CALL, but it gives me the same error. Sorry for the late reply.